# How can I reference a type in lib.dom.d.ts in another declaration file?

Tags: javascript, typescript, indexeddb

I'm pretty new to TypeScript and trying to make automated tests where I dependency-inject IndexedDB into my code, but the library I'm using to mock IDB doesn't have a `.d.ts`, so I tried to roll my own simple declaration file to get around this, which looked something like this:

```
declare let fakeIndexedDB: IDBFactory;

declare module 'fake-indexeddb' {
  export var fakeIndexedDB;
}
```

However, when I tried using this type, I got the error:

```
type 'typeof import("fake-indexeddb")' is missing the following properties from type 'IDBFactory': cmp, deleteDatabase, open
```

Mousing over in VSCode, it looks like the type of IDBFactory is this type from lib.dom.d.ts:

```
declare var IDBFactory: {
    prototype: IDBFactory;
    new(): IDBFactory;
};
```

But what I wanted to import was the interface type directly above it. How would I say in my declaration file that I want to reference the interface in lib.dom.ts, not the var that uses it? I can see that jsdom was able to make a class in their .d.ts that references DOM types with both an interface and var, but they also don't use "declare module".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem**

The problem with this code:

```
declare let fakeIndexedDB: IDBFactory;

declare module 'fake-indexeddb' {
  export var fakeIndexedDB;
}
```

is that the type of the exported `fakeIndexedDB` is `any`. It's a different variable than the one declared above it. Basically, `fake-indexeddb` defined like that is a module that exports a single variable called `fakeIndexedDB` of unspecified type.

**Solution**

What you should do instead is this:

```
declare module 'fake-indexeddb' {
  const fakeIndexedDB: IDBFactory;

  export = fakeIndexedDB;
}
```

Whether to use `export =`, `export` or `export default` depends on how the actual JavaScript library is built. The above syntax is recommended if `fake-indexeddb` exports a single member and it's meant to work well when imported using the `require` function. See if it works, and if not, consult the source code.

Comment: Thank you! I raise a PepsiMAX to your catching that scoping bug!!

Comment: I raise some tea to you succeeding!